# Multiple shared footers in Rails 3

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails-3, footer

Is there a way of rendering different shared footers in rails, so for example i would like one footer for the homepage and then a different footer throughout the site.

has anyone done this before? i was thinking that an if statement would work depending upon the page viewed? not sure if this is correct

Any help appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you had the following layouts:

- app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
- app/views/layouts/home.html.erb

You'd just specify the layout in your homepage controller as in

```
class HomeController < ApplicationController
  layout 'home'
  #everything else follows...
end
```

The rest of your views will use the default, which is `application.html.erb`.

Comment: I was wondering  what i would do if i wanted different layouts for pages within the same controller?

Comment: its ok i got it render :layout 'name' in the action where i want that layout